# I am trying to parse information from a JSON URL file using two user inputs from python

Tags: python, json, for-loop, parsing

This is the code that works successfully by asking a user one input, which in this case, is the state

```
import requests
import simplejson as json

response = requests.get("https://api.covidtracking.com/v1/states/ca/daily.json")

json_test = response.json()

print("Enter the state for which the COVID data should be retrieved (e.g. TX): ")
user_state = input()


count = 0
for i in json_test:
    i = count
    count = count + 1
    state = (json_test[i]['state'])
    dates = (json_test[i]['date'])
    

    if state == user_state:
            
        death = (json_test[i]['death'])
        print("State: " + str(state))
        print("Date: " + str(dates))
        print("Death(s)" + str(death))
        print("===============")
```

the output would be something like:

```
Date: 20201112
Death(s)18108
===============
State: CA
Date: 20201111
Death(s)18070
===============
State: CA
Date: 20201110
Death(s)18001
===============
State: CA
Date: 20201109
Death(s)17977
===============
```

But I'm trying to implement the option for the user to enter the US state AND date on the command line with a something like:

```
Enter the state for which the COVID data should be retrieved (e.g. TX): CA
Enter the date for which the COVID data should be retrieved (e.g. 20201219): 20210219
```

The code I have tried is:

```
import requests
import simplejson as json

response = requests.get("https://api.covidtracking.com/v1/states/ca/daily.json")

json_test = response.json()

print("Enter the state for which the COVID data should be retrieved (e.g. TX): ")
user_state = input()
print("Enter the date for which the COVID data should be retrieved (e.g. 20201219): ")
user_date = input()

count = 0
for i in json_test:
    i = count
    count = count + 1
    state = (json_test[i]['state'])
    dates = (json_test[i]['date'])
    

    if state == user_state and dates == user_date:
            
        death = (json_test[i]['death'])
        print("State: " + str(state))
        print("Date: " + str(dates))
        print("Death(s)" + str(death))
        print("===============")
```

However, my output has no results but no errors either. I do now know why it is not working

Comment: I see dates in the JSON that are integers like `20210305` not strings. You could try converting the user input to an int or process the dates.

Answer (score 0):

Here value of dates received from url has datatype of `int` you need to convert it into `string` for comparison. This code will work perfectly:

```
import requests
import simplejson as json

response = requests.get("https://api.covidtracking.com/v1/states/ca/daily.json")

json_test = response.json()


user_state = input("Enter the state for which the COVID data should be retrieved (e.g. TX): ")

user_date = input("Enter the date for which the COVID data should be retrieved (e.g. 20201219): ")

count = 0
for i in json_test:
    i = count
    count = count + 1
    state = (json_test[i]['state'])
    dates = (json_test[i]['date'])


    if((state == user_state)and(str(dates) == user_date)):

        death = (json_test[i]['death'])
        print("State: " + str(state))
        print("Date: " + str(dates))
        print("Death(s): " + str(death))
        print("===============")
```

**Input**

```
Enter the state for which the COVID data should be retrieved (e.g. TX): CA
Enter the date for which the COVID data should be retrieved (e.g. 20201219): 20210305
```

**Output**

```
State: CA
Date: 20210305
Death(s): 53448
===============
```